# How to install python-qt3?

Tags: python, qt3, software-installation

I'm new in Linux environment and I need to install `python-qt3` on Ubuntu 13.10. How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu dropped Qt 3 packages on favor of Qt4. You should install Qt 4 instead:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but, when i try to install gerix-wifi, it's need qt3, there's a new version for gerix-wifi?

Comment: Beats me. You should check their front page.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the below solution.

This package is still available in Ubuntu 12.04 which is an LTS release.
I would recommend you that you use this Ubuntu version as it is more stable.

Anyways, If you want to use your current Ubuntu you may do this:
edit the "/etc/apt/sources.list" file using this command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add these two lines at the end of it.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

after that run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-qt3
```

If this is successful please let me know.
I am not sure this is the right way to do this so anyone is welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: i did that, but it appera an error, it say "package python-qt3 is not available"

Comment: Oh! I am sorry try the second method. there is no qt3 in pip it must be a Ubuntu Package.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package which have both Pyqt3 and Pyqt4, Download and install it.

http://www.develer.com/%7Enaufraghi/PyQt3Support/PyQt3Support-PyQt4.4.4-gpl-r4.tar.gz

If you had installed pyqt4 already , then you can extend it to support pyqt3 also by using this patch.

http://www.develer.com/%7Enaufraghi/PyQt3Support/PyQt3Support-PyQt4.4.4-gpl-r4.patch